# Execute a stored procedure from Excel that itself generates dynamic code and executes it

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, stored-procedures

I generated an SQL query that generates an SQL query and executes it.

This query I want to have either in a view or in Excel to give it to users who don't use SQL Server Management Studio.

I found [several](http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.de/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html) [blogentries](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba.aspx) describing how to run stored procedures from Excel.

Sadly they don't work for me.

Here the query / SQL of stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @template nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @script nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(max)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
select name from  master.sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE '%REPORTING'
OPEN c

SET @template = 'SELECT 
    ''CUSTOMER_PLACEHOLDER'' AS Customer
      ,rd.[ReportName]        
      ,min(ri.RenderingStart) AS FirstRequest
      ,max(ri.RenderingEnd) AS LastRequest
      ,count(ri.ReportInstanceGUID) AS TimesRendered
  FROM [DBNAME_PLACEHOLDER].[dbo].[ReportDefinition] rd
  LEFT JOIN DBNAME_PLACEHOLDER.dbo.ReportJob rj ON rj.ReportDefinitionGUID = rd.ReportDefinitionGUID
  LEFT JOIN DBNAME_PLACEHOLDER.dbo.ReportInstance ri ON ri.ReportJobGUID = rj.ReportJobGUID
  GROUP BY rd.ReportName'

SET @script = ''

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbname

DECLARE @first bit
SET @first = 1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @customer nvarchar(6)

    SET @customer = SUBSTRING(@dbname,14,6)
    IF @first = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @script = @template
            SET @first = 0
        END
    ELSE
        --SET @script = @script+'
        --UNION ALL
        --'+@template

    SET @script = REPLACE(@script,'CUSTOMER_PLACEHOLDER', @customer)
    SET @script = REPLACE(@script,'DBNAME_PLACEHOLDER', @dbname)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c 
    INTO @dbname

END
    EXEC (@script)
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

The `ELSE` part has been commented to see the error in Excel.

The query runs when executing it like that.

When calling it in Excel I get the following Error (verified same is happening when starting Excel as Administrator):

[image: Errorpic]

I have no idea where to continue. Table value functions won't also work, as EXEC is not allowed in them. If possible I want to keep the dynamic part as the number and names of the databases may change - and I want to keep it unspecific.

Hints?

Comment: Where you say EXEC(@Script) also dump it to a table so you can run it by hand and check the error. It probably has to do with the code you want to execute. If you can run the Proc from the Management Studio but not from Excel then it sould have to do with the way parameters are passsed (escape quotes that kind of stuff)

Comment: I do not provide/need any parameters. Calling the stored procedure or executing the code like that works fine. So the execution itself should not be a problem.

Comment: Are you calling it as the same user? That can be an issue, since the dynamic SQL is executed as the caller, they might not have all the rights to the tables. You can fix that with EXECUTE AS clause.

Comment: Both times with same domain user.